# $c_1\cosh(x)+c_2\sinh(x)=A\cosh(x+y)$ always true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

My question: Can I rewrite $c_1\cosh(x)+c_2\sinh(x)$, which is a solution to a differential equation as

$$A\cosh(x+x_0)$$
introducing the new constants of integration $A$ and $x_0$? How can I deal with $c_1=0$?

This is how I can set up a relationship between the coefficients:

$A\cosh(x+x_0)=A\cosh(x)\cosh(x_0)+A\sinh(x)\sin(x_0)$

Compare coefficients:

$c_1=A\cosh(x_0)$ and $c_2=A\sinh(x_0)$.

Now square and subtract both equations: 
$$c_1^2-c_2^2=A^2 \implies A=\pm\sqrt{c_1^2-c_2^2}.$$

Now devide second equation by first equation:

$$\tanh(x_0)=c_2/c_1 \implies x_0=\tanh^{-1}(c_2/c_1 )$$

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  If you have $|c_1|<|c_2|$ then your linear combination has a real zero and you can't fit it to a hyperbolic cosine with real parameters.

You can use a hyperbolic sine for the combined function in that case [$A \sinh (x+x_0)$], or use the hyperbolic cosine with complex parameters.

Still there remains the degenerate case $|c_1|=|c_2|$.  In that situation you are forced to turn to an exponential function; hyperbolic functions with real or complex parameters do not fit.

So it looks like you have to consider the separate cases unless you have advance knowledge about the relative absolute values of $|c_1|$ and $|c_2|$.